# Complex Types and Function Imports in POCO entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

I update my edmx file with a new stored procedure and expect it to generate FunctionImports and ComplexTypes for this procedure automatically, but no luck.

I am new to Entity Framework, Please help

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? if any, please post them here. This may not be the exact thing your for, did you try creating new edmx file?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error, just my complex type and function imports does not automatically get created, They are suppose to create automatically, aren't they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function imports or complex types are never generated automatically. You must open Model Browser and create them manually. Adding stored procedure to the model will only allow you creating the import. The reason is that not every procedure is used for import. Some procedures can be mapped to modification operations (insert, update, delete) on entities.